# Extracting a remote MySQL Database without MyODBC?

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to get a MySQL Dump of a database that is not stored locally. I have the connection string to the database located on another server, but it doesn't seem like MySQLDump wants to do anything if the server is remote.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`MySQLDump` has a `-h` parameter to connect to a remote host.

First try the mysql client application:

```
mysql -h your.server.com -uYourUser -pYourPass
```

If that works, use the same format for MySQLDump

```
mysqldump -h your.server.com -uYourUser -pYourPass --all-databases
```

#### Edit for ajreal:

By default, mysqld (the MySQL server) will run on 3306, and mysql (the client application) will connect using that port. However, if you changed your configuration, update your command accordingly. For example for port 3307, use

```
mysql -h your.server.com -P 3307 -uYourUser -pYourPass
```

Check your MySQL configfile to see how you can connect to your MySQL server.

Comment: Where is the port of connection OR you assume is the default 3306?

Comment: too paranoid of me, please ignore me

Comment: @ajreal: It's a valid point, might be why he can't be connecting. I don't expect any reply from the user though, probably a driveby - it **might benefit future visitors** though, so that's reason enough for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is example, how to extract mysql db named 'abc123' direct to zip,  w/o super big text dump file on disk.

mysqldump -u root --opt --databases abc123 | gzip > /tmp/abc123.export.sql.gz

Comment: Code-only answers are considered low quality: make sure to provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem.